# How to collect all results from a web API in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, python-responses

I am collecting data from a web API by using a Python script. The web API provides maximum 50 results (`"size":50`). However, I need to collect all the results. Please let me know how can I do it. My initial code is available below. Thank you in advance.

```
def getData():
    headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }

    data = '{"size":50,"sites.recruitment_status":"ACTIVE", "sites.org_state_or_province":"VA"}'
    response = requests.post('https://clinicaltrialsapi.cancer.gov/v1/clinical-trials', headers=headers, data=data)

    print(response.json())
```

Comment: This same thing happened to me with the USDA API. In the end, I ended up making a list of query strings of 50 items long and just looped through those, getting 50 result sets at a time. Can you share more of your code? It appears incomplete.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with both, incompatible, versions of python? How can we hope to beat pagination of results if we don't know how often the API updates? Did you read the documentation for the specific API you're using?

Comment: What part are you stuck on? I'd think you'd just grab the results one page at a time and save them to a collection. What part of that don't you know how to do?

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer already given you can get then total results from the initial json. You can then use a loop to increment for batches

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://clinicaltrialsapi.cancer.gov/v1/clinical-trials"
r = requests.get(url).json()
num_results = int(r['total'])
results_per_request = 50
total = 0
while total < num_results:
    total+=results_per_request
    print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is in the doc :

https://clinicaltrialsapi.cancer.gov/#!/Clinical45trials/searchTrialsByGet

**GET clinical-trials**

> Filters all clinical trials based upon supplied filter params. Filter
>   params may be any of the fields in the schema as well as any of the
>   following params...
>
> size: limit the amount of results a supplied amount (default is 10,
>   max is 50)
>
> from: start the results from a supplied starting point (default is 0)
>
> ...

So you just have to specify a "from" value, and increment it 50 by 50.

Comment: Thank you. How to find the end of the results?

Comment: when you query the API, at some point you'll get less than 50 results, that means it's the end.